# Adding values to already initialized object array in Java?

Tags: java, android

I'm developing for the Android platform and, to simplify the question, I'm using pseudo-names for the entities.

I have an object array stuff[] of the class StuffClass[].

```
StuffClass stuff[]={
new StuffClass(Argument, argument, argument),
new StuffClass(argument, argument, argument)
};
```

I have an activity returning a result of three arguments that I want to then use to add a new object to stuff[].  I've done so as follows:

```
stuff[stuff.length]=new StuffClass(argument, argument, argument);
```

and I get ArrayOutOfBounds (Figured that would happen).

So how might I go about creating a new object in the stuff[] array?

Comment: you can use ArrayList in your case

Comment: Arrays are fixed length. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html ; use a `List`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are static you can't change size without creating a new one before. Instead of that  you can use a **dynamic** data structure such as an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Example:

```
List<MyType> objects = new ArrayList<>();
objects.add(new MyType());
```

Here you forget about array size.

Comment: Are the method calls to ArrayLists the same as to Arrays?  Like if I change the Array stuff[] to an Array List stuff[] will all my other calls to things like stuff.length, stuff[i].stuffMethod, etc be the same?

Comment: @NicolasMustaro An array has no methods. As you say to access to an object you do by position like `stuff[i]` in List you can do it the same, `list.get(i)`. This [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) may help you.

Answer (score 1):

`Array` in Java is little bit special, it's length is fixed when it's initialized, you can not extend it later on.

What you can do is to create a new array, and use `System.arraycopy` to generate a new array, here's the sample code:

```
  String[] arr1 = new String[]{"a", "b"};
  String[] arr2 = new String[3];

  System.arraycopy(arr1, 0, arr2, 0, 2);
  arr2[2] = "c";
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot increase the size of an existing array.  Once it's created, the size of the array is fixed.

You will need to create another bigger array and copy the items from the old array to the new array.

A better alternative is to use an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).  When you `add` items to an `ArrayList`, the capacity will grow behind the scenes if needed; you don't have to worry about increasing the size.

Answer (score 0):

in java arrays are fixed length. you need to initialise them with the desired length.

Consider using a Collection such as [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) which will handle everything for you.

```
List<StuffClass> myList = new ArrayList<>();
myList.add(...);
```

Lists support similar behaviour to arrays ie:

```
myList.set(i, elem);
myArray[i] = elem;

elem = myList.get(i);
elem = myArray[i];

len = myList.size();
len = myArray.length;
```

You can then convert the list to an array.

```
StuffClass[] myArray = myList.toArray(new StuffClass[myList.size()]);
```

If you don't want to use lists consider using [System.arrayCopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) to create a new array with more elements.

[read here for a good description.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the ArrayList to do this

arraylist.add(object);